# Mail does not send while running RUNNABLE JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, email, jar

I'm trying to send an email using package `javax.mail.*`

Everything works fine in eclipse, but **after I export to Runnable Jar email won't send**. Can you help me understand what might be the problem? 
If there is a problem with using `"using javax.mail.*"` is there an alternative library to use?

When exporting I use "Package required libraries into generated JAR"

Thank you.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 

public class sadasddas {

    public static String ErrorMsg;
    private static final String MAIL_SERVER = "smtp";
    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.mail.com";
    private static final int SMTP_HOST_PORT = 587;
    private static final String USER_NAME = "someting@mail.com";  
    private static final String PASSWORD = "*****************";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] to = { "dest@mail.com" }; 
        String subject = "Java Send Mail Attachement Example";
        String body = "Welcome to Java Mail!<h1>Hello</h1>";
        String[] attachFiles = new String[3];
        attachFiles[0] = "C:/Til/Result/download.txt";
        attachFiles[1] = "C:/Til/Result/Printer.txt";
        attachFiles[2] = "C:/Til/Result/software.txt";
        try {
            sendEmailWithAttachments(to, subject, body, attachFiles);
            System.out.println("Email Sent....!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not send email....!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String[] to, String subject, String body, String[] attachFiles) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
       Properties properties = System.getProperties();     
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", USER_NAME);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", PASSWORD);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_HOST_PORT);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
            }
        }; 
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);        
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {       
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USER_NAME));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }
            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
                for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
                    MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    try {
                        attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
                }
            }
            message.setContent(multipart); 
            Transport transport = session.getTransport(MAIL_SERVER);
            transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("Sent Message Successfully....");
        }
        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace on standard out?

Comment: Nо. Everything goes smoothly. " Sent Message Successfully....Email Sent....!"

Comment: I have opened CMD and ran my runnable JAR  (java -jar sadasddas.jar ) No errors, email was send. But for some reason it's still not working in if I run it from desktop.

Comment: Learn how to attach a debugger to your code so you can see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account not only your question but also what you wrote in the comment, the problem was that you were trying to run the jar file from the desktop with double click, which you can do with GUI apps, but not with console apps. For a console app you can create a .bat file starting the cmd and running the jar file in cmd. Then you can create a shortcut to the .bat file on your desktop and run it with double click.

The .bat file should look like this:

```
echo off
start cmd.exe /c
cd /d "d:\path_to_the_jar_file\"
java -jar "My Program.jar"
pause
echo on
```